# How to construct SNS filter policy to match partial S3 object key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have created a subscription to an SNS topic where all of the events will be from S3 ObjectCreated:Put actions.  I only want to receive the notifications where the S3 object key contains the string 'KLWX'.  What should that filter policy look like?  The notification data is below, however the 'Message' attribute value is given as a string, not a JSON object.  I just expanded it for easier reading.

```
{
"SignatureVersion": "1",
"Type": "Notification",
"TopicArn": "xxx",
"Message": {
    "Records": [{
        "eventVersion": "2.0",
        "eventSource": "aws:s3",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "eventTime": "2018-01-18T20:16:27.590Z",
        "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
        "userIdentity": {
            "principalId": "xxx"
        },
        "requestParameters": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "xxx"
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "x-amz-request-id": "6CF3314E6D6B7671",
            "x-amz-id-2": "tJdr3KDcAsp1tuGdo6y4jBLkYXsEDEeVPcvQ1SWQoLXWsZL81WUzbloDe1HxbhGes4u0tY9Jh+g="
        },
        "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "NewNEXRADLevel2Object",
            "bucket": {
                "name": "xxx",
                "ownerIdentity": {
                    "principalId": "xxx"
                },
                "arn": "xxx"
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "KCBW/881/20180118-201329-015-I",
                "size": 16063,
                "eTag": "772cd2d2e82b22448792308755891350",
                "sequencer": "005A61009B8EC82991"
            }
        }
    }]
},
"UnsubscribeURL": "xxx",
"Signature": "xxx",
"Timestamp": "2018-01-18T20:16:27.626Z",
"SigningCertURL": "xxx",
"Subject": "Amazon S3 Notification",
"MessageId": "ed6a0365-4af2-5497-9be0-51be4829cdee"
```

}

Comment: I found this [aws article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/) to be helpful

Answer (score 4):

Filter policy similar to the one below worked for me. This requires FilterPolicyScope to be set to MessageBody.

```
"Records" : {
  "s3" : {
    "object" : {
      "key" : [
        { "prefix" : "KLWX/" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to add both suffix and prefix?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this on the S3. When you create the event, you can use a combination of prefix/suffix to filter which object sends the notification to your SNS topic.

Assuming the bucket name is `YourBucket`, and your object key is `KCBW/881/20180118-201329-015-I`, you have to configure the S3 event on YourBucket with `prefix = KLWX/`

Comment: That's unfortunate since I do not own the bucket or the SNS topic.  I'm subscribed to the public topic, and I know that the topic notifications are caused by S3:ObjectCreated:Put events.  There is a relatively new feature on the SNS subscriptions to 'Edit subscription filter policy'.  Is there no way to use this feature?

Comment: You could use it, but even for that I guess you would need access to the account which owns the topic. Read the details here -
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html

 I recommended the above approach assuming this is all within your own account.

Comment: @abiydv Did you find a way to make that work through filter policy? Perhaps there is a "contains" filter that could be applied to the json-like value for the "Message" key?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe and add a target for an AWS Lambda function.  In that function, you can code up your logic.  If needed, you could send out another SNS message from there, or store/process the data as needed.
[image]